# Where can I find REMOTE EOS API

Tags: blockchain, eos

Tell me please where can I find remote `EOS` API, I don't want to start the `EOS` node locally, because there are 170 million blocks. It will take a very long time for complete synchronization.
Interested in a fully functional API with the ability to send transactions.
I did not find any endpoints on the official website https://eos.io/.
Found just some small commands described here : [https://developers.eos.io/](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/get_account).
On my own did not find any normal service.

Answer (score 1):

I am just getting started and haven't tried sending any transactions yet. But I did find...

https://seed01.eosusa.news/v1/chain/

example:
https://seed01.eosusa.news/v1/chain/get_info

**Edit:** After my original post here I also discovered https://eosflare.io/api It's not the standard EOS Chain API but it does provide access to the EOS data indirectly.

--Jacob